# React how to know how many child components a parent has?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I try to use `Object.keys(children).length` and there is only 1 child component, then it gives me the amount of keys the one child component has. This approach only works if there are multiple child components. How would I find the amount of child component a component has?

```js
<Navbar>
  <Component 1/>
</Navbar>
```

```js
const Navbar = ({ children }) => {
  console.log(Object.keys(children).length);   //displays properly only if more than 1 child component
  console.log(children.length);                //undefined
  ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React.Children.count method will help you get what you need.

```
const Navbar = ({ children }) => {
    child_count = React.Children.count(children)
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren